# GetResponse API integration Using fetch() is not working

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

**GetResponse API integration Using Fetch API method not working**

The following SMS is showing in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked:
> The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
> https‍://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts.
> (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Code is given below:

// main.js

```
// POST request using fetch()
fetch("https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts", {
    
    // Adding method type
    method: "POST",
    
    // Adding body or contents to send
    body: JSON.stringify(
        {
            campaign : {
                campaignId: "5D8Qm"
            },
            name: "xyz",
            email: "fdfdfd@gmail.com"
        }
    ),
    
    // Adding headers to the request
    headers: {
        
        
        "X-Auth-Token": "api-key o9q5s264jbp9dws0nsevnagqdst81esh",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
})

// Converting to JSON
.then(response => response.json())

// Displaying results to console
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: Check your request and response headers. This is classic CORS issue (more: [access-control-allow-origin](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors/access-control-allow-origin))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, When I used the cURL, it was working properly, but when I was working with the Fetch API, it was not working . I want to know the reason for this.

Comment: "I want to know the reason for this" ->  the CORS is a browser related thing. and that is why when you use cURL it didn't happen. it is a browser-specific defensive mechanism

Comment: If you use cURL, ensure you use it with: `curl -s -D - https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts`, where `-s`: *Avoid showing progress bar*, and `-D`: *Dump headers to a file* and `-`: *forces the redirect to stdout*. The headers of the HTTP protocol are important. the CORS standard happens within these headers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic CORS issue as **azbarcea** said.

As for your comment about why cURL works but Fetch API not, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506848/accessing-api-works-fine-with-curl-but-not-with-fetch-api) in Stack Overflow.